# Any research on health-outcome measures that most likely cause policy-change?

Tags: research, health-outcomes

A lot of medical research is done with outcome measures that may not have strong impact on health policy? Is there any research on outcome measures that more strongly influence health policy? I made a quite comprehensive search but this did not provide any relevant papers (or I couldn't identify them correctly).

Comment: Hello st4co4, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions on this site are required to show prior research. As described in the help center and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links or references to what you've found in your search. For example, you might include a quote of one of those studies of outcome measures without strong impact. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Or at least just tell us what you searched for and where.